# React stateless functional component should return null but receiving error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple component to display invalid form entries, which obviously should only render a message when said form entries are invalid. As far as I can tell, I used the conditional return statements correctly, but I'm still getting an error.

Here's the component:

import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

```
function FormErrors ({formErrors}) {
    Object.keys({formErrors}).map((field, i) => {
        if ({formErrors}[field].length > 0) {
            return (
                <p key={i}>{field} {formErrors[field]}</p>
            )
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    })
}

export default FormErrors;
```

The props being passed in:

```
formErrors: {email: '', password: ''};
```

And the error message I'm receiving:

`Invariant Violation: FormErrors(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Nothing was returned from render.

You're missing a `return`

```
function FormErrors ({formErrors}) {
    return Object.keys({formErrors}).map((field, i) => {
    // ^^ add this return
        if ({formErrors}[field].length > 0) {
            return (
                <p key={i}>{field} {formErrors[field]}</p>
            )
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Yeppppp, there it is